# Currency rounding inconsistencies in Dojo.currency

Tags: dojo

im working with dojo.currency format.  There seems to be inconstancies on how it rounds, im trying to find if im doing something wrong:

```
dojo.currency.format("66.315",{currency:"USD"})
"$66.31"
dojo.currency.format("669.315",{currency:"USD"})
"$669.32"
```

In the above example both prices would be rounded to 32 cents, but for some reason i end up with 2 different amounts.

Comment: Is it consistent across all web-browsers?

Comment: It is confirmed on Chrome, Firefox, android browser and IOS browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like dojo.currency is using dojo.number.round under the covers, and dojo.number.round uses the javascript toFixed.  which is known to have the floating point problem.

using Math.round(number*Math.pow(10,places))/Math.pow(10,places) instead